# map sql date to list of java.time.MonthDay

Tags: java, spring, date, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I define some holidays for Markets in my database:

```
MarketA | 2018-10-04
MarketA | 2018-10-05 
MarketB | 2018-02-15
MarketB | 2018-02-16
```

**Schema** is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MarketHolidays  
   (
     MarketName varchar(50) NOT NULL,    
     HolidayDate date NOT NULL
   )
```

I am looking to map the result set to the map and parse the dates from sql query to Java `MonthDay`. There should be one key for each market with their list of holidays. Can you please as I don't know how to map and parse to `MonthDay`.

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class HolidayServiceDAOImpl implements HolidayServiceDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate


    @Override
    public Map<String, List<java.time.MonthDay>> getHolidays() {
        String sql = "select MarketName, HolidayDate from dbo.MarketHolidays ";
        Map<String, List<MonthDay>> holidays = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should retrieve `LocalDate` objects from the database and convert them using `MonthDay.from(localDateFromDatabase)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get a Map directly as you desire. You need to do something like this

Considering you have a pojo like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MarketHolidays {
  String  MarketName;
  Date holidayDate;

}
```

Then your conversion logic would be

```
String sql = "select * from dbo.MarketHolidays ";
List<MarketHolidays> marketHolidaysList = jdbcTemplate.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, MarketHolidays.class);

 Map<String, List<MonthDay>> map = Maps.newHashMap();

 marketHolidaysList.forEach(m -> {
  Date holidayDate = m.getHolidayDate();
  LocalDate date = holidayDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
  MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.of(date.getMonth(), date.getDayOfMonth());

  map.computeIfAbsent(m.getMarketName(), s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(monthDay);
});
```

Comment: can you edit your answer based on return type being `List<Map<String, Object>>` from `jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql)` ?

Comment: I get the error `Error:(35, 17) java: no suitable method found for collect(java.util.stream.Collector<com.batch.domain.HolidayDescriptionModel,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>)
    method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable` My model is HolidayDescriptionModel

Comment: which version of java are you using

Comment: i am using 1.8 version. please edit accordingly so I can test. and even better if can use java.util.date on the model

Comment: `List<MarketHolidays> marketHolidaysList = jdbcTemplate.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, MarketHolidays.class);`  >> incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 2. is this how it should be mapped?